# Exercise about Stokes with alternative solution

Tags: analysis, stokes-theorem

> **Exercise text** Calculate $ \int_\gamma  ydx-xdy+z^2dz $ where $ \gamma $ is the closed curve generated by the intersection of $ x^2+y^2=4 $ with $ z=y^2 $.

**My solution and question**  I tried to solve it by doing the line integral and it comes to me $ 4\pi \sqrt2 $, the problem is that with stokes I can not see what is the surface of intersection.

Comment: Have you tried to write the surface in cartesian form?

Comment: @DavideMorgante No, I can not write the intersection surface in Cartesian form.

Comment: How about something like $y^2 = 4-x^2 \Rightarrow z = 4-x^2 = f(x,y)$

Comment: This topic could help you https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2286077/554978

Comment: @JackJ. Thank you very much for your answer, you have been very helpful in solving my problem

Comment: You should get $\pm 8 \pi$ though, not $4 \pi \sqrt 2$.